# Mono - getting disk partitions under Linux

Tags: linux, mono, partition, disk

I can use System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives to the get the list of the logical disk drives.  On my Raspberry Pi, I will get this list:

```
/  
/boot  
/run/user/1000/gvfs  
/media/pi/16GBSD  

(where /media/pi/16GBSD is a SD card in an external USB card reader)
```

My question is, on a Linux system, how can I get the list of the actual disk partition names?  On my Pi, those would be mmcblk0p0, mmcblk0p1 and sda1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `lsblk` is what you are looking for.

[man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html)

Comment: That's is a command line program that returns the information.  And yes, I could shell out and execute the command and parse the results.  But, there should be (hopefully) a way of querying the OS for the information using library calls.